# C# MVC additional thread per user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, tcp, .net-4.0

We have a server application that sends and receives messages from an external tcp server. We have already implemented a client application to connect with our server application. The client connects to our server app and holds the connection until it the client application is shut down. There is a constant flow of messages from server to client and back.

Now I need to implement that into a MVC web application. My idea was to start a additional thread when the user logs in and connect inside this thread with our server application. The thread will end if the user logs out after a timeout. The question is, how do I implement this thread that this thread stays active between requests per user. The callbacks to the client will be realised with `SignalR`.

Can I simply use

```
System.Threading.Task.TaskFactory.StartNew()
```

to start this thread? Or do I need to use the Thread object?

Comment: Thread per connection is a really inefficient pattern. Better to have some state and then do everything asynchronously. This will allow a small number of thread-pool threads to handle a huge number of connections.

Comment: The thing is, that every user has his own unique id and, by design, needs an individual thread for our server application. And the max number of users is not greater than 30 per installation. And these users will never be logged in at the same time, so there is no big problem there.

Comment: Client needing some state does not mean separate thread. Nor does server using thread per connection mean a client (such as the ASP.NET-MVC web app) would itself need separate threads.

Comment: The server app (not the MVC web app) handles every connected user in a seperate thread. Every thread has to have a unique user id. Unfortunatly we cannot change the way the server app handles the users

Comment: You probably just want some kind of user/session table class maintaining some kind of user state object per active user.  This object can contain a thread procedure that could either be invoked explicitly using the System.Threading.Thread class or using a Task wrapper and performs the user-specific activity, and this thread procedure can then exit or be terminated when the user is logged off (/ removed from the table).